# Choosing a snowy destination in Europe for travel by train

Tags: trains, europe, winter, mountains, snow

What regions are easily reachable by train from the Netherlands and are (almost) sure to have snow in winter? I'm trying to avoid skiing areas as those are crowded, expensive, sold out and geared towards skiing.
We are just looking to have some time in the snow, build an igloo, have some snowballfights.

Norway, Sweden and Finland are sure to have snow but are too far away. Most of Germany is not high enough. So this leaves France, Switzerland and Austria (Italy also but Austria and Switzerland are nearer).

Currently I am tracing train tracks on Google Maps with the height map turned on because destinations above 1,500 m are very likely to have snow. Maybe there are better resources?

When choosing a destinations should I also consider the orientation of slopes? If we are going to spend time wandering around during the day, does it matter much if we are on a South or North (East or West) face of a mountain?

Comment: All areas in Europa which are snow certain will have wintersports. So excluding wintersport areas will make this impossible to answer.

Comment: If you don't want skiing, what do you want? Just to see some snow? Get some picturesque photos? Sledging, snowball fights? Do you just want to ski for free without having to pay resort fees? Explaining what you are actually looking for, rather than what you don't want, will help people answer.

Comment: Another option is the Pyrenees. You can almost reach Andorra by train from Amsterdam, but it might be cheaper and quicker to fly to Norway.

Comment: No snow in Germany? https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/dec/02/snow-chaos-southern-germany-munich-airport-suspends-flights

Comment: I agree with @StuartF. And why would you exclude areas below 1500m? Otherwise Denmark could possibly work. And at the beginning of December there was snow (almost) all over Germany. It also depends on when you want to go. Please specify.

Comment: @WeatherVane good call. You can get to La Tor de Querol (Latour-de-Carol) by train from Holland, changing in Paris. And from there there's the [regional train](https://rodalies.gencat.cat/ca/linies_estacions_i_trens/index.html?linia=r3) which goes to Barcelona and stops at several places in the mountains on its way (some skiing places, some not). Basically [option 3 here](https://www.seat61.com/international-trains/trains-from-Amsterdam.htm#Amsterdam-Spain)

Comment: OP doesn't actually say they want to ski, only that snowy places might be popular with skiers. What they do say is "we are going to spend time wandering around during the day". If you just want to experience snow, look at weather maps after you arrive to find out how far you need to travel. Snow is only predictable in the popular resorts.

Comment: Re the edit: you can learn how to build an igloo in the (Spanish) Pyrenees too: see [Ready to build an igloo?](https://www.visitpirineus.com/en/blog/ready-build-igloo)

Comment: Lots of Germany is high enough. You do not need to go to 2000 m high. Not even to 1000 m in fact. There are mountain ranges with high snow probability and cross-country skiing (that mostly requires natural snow) that are mostly below 1000 m elevation.

Comment: Next week it might even snow in the Netherlands, certainly in Belgium and Germany, but as the weather has been rather warm so far it is likely to change to warm soon.

Comment: @Willeke - not sure I agree. For skiing mountains are needed. It can be snowy in flat areas too.

Comment: Where in the Netherlands are you based? How long do you wish to stay at your destination? What is a reasonable max travel duration? (From Amsterdam, even the Jura or the Vosges are easily 8 hours away). Do you plan to use only public transportation, or is renting a car at your destination OK? (Outside of big ski resorts public transport is often limited). How long in advance will you be planning your trip? Which month would you target? Even well over 1500m it can be quite difficult to have guaranteed snow all winter, while a week in advance you'll know. Can you avoid holiday periods?

Comment: While Europe might not be big compared to other continents, OP does indicate not looking at nearby, to Dutch standards, location. So a roll back.

Comment: Sweden is not that far: from the Netherlands, take the train to Hamburg, then a night train to Stockholm

Comment: regarding trains, there are night trains from Bruxelles to Austria, so that can make it more convenient than other places

Comment: The massive prevalence of "snow cannons" in ski resorts indicates that even for those snow isn't exactly guaranteed. To my knowledge there are very few places in Europe south of mid-Sweden that have guaranteed snow cover all winter, and if they are somebody has most assuredly built a resort of some kind there.

Comment: The Vosges mountains in France are only a stone's throw from you and a popular destination for Dutch and Belgians. It's not always guaranteed to have snow (it used to have a lot more) but you should have a good idea whether or not there'll be snow from looking at weather patterns a couple of weeks in advance. They're expecting heavy snow in the next few days. It tends to be a lot cheaper than the Alps, they have some webcams up there too.

Comment: @Reno Much like Black forest (maybe +cuisine -service ferroviaire, but things may have changed recently?) Turn this one into an answer?

Comment: @xLeitix Availability of snow depends on the height, usually there is enough snow above 2000m in January and February. Snow cannons help to start the season earlier (November) and to ensure having enough snow in critical spots. The challenge for the OP is to find high-altitude (>2000m) locations which offer more than just skiing.

Comment: @njzk2 I was unaware of the nighttrain from Hamburg to Sweden. That would make a journey of 24 hours, thereabouts. Which is just doable. For reference, here is a blogpost about it: https://www.seat61.com/trains-and-routes/hamburg-to-stockholm-by-sleeper-train.htm

Comment: Assuming a wider scope of "Europe" (as in the title) I want to point out another destination-s (apart from Alps and Scandinavia) which are quite snow-safe, and well accessible by train: Mountains at the CZ/SK/PL borders, i.e. the Giant Mountains, Hrubý Jeseník, and the High Tatras. There _is_, of course, ski tourism (as Willeke mentioned). From Amsterdam these are at 20-24 hrs - still doable with maybe a night in Prague. Not an answer because it's been yeeears that I've been there...

Answer (score 20):

When all you want to do is actually to walk (and play) in the snow, if you do have a strong preference for train riding, and if you are not bound to make a fixed booking long in advance, you should consider the [Harz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harz) mountains (Germany):

- Not 100% snow proof, but
- most easily accessible by train from the Netherlands (e.g. some 6h from Amsterdam), and
- not primarily a skiing destination (so less crowded).

Check local weather forecast (or [webcam](https://www.hsb-wr.de/Webcam/Brockenplateau-Talblick/)) and, when promising, book accommodation in one of the picturesque towns at the mountain foot (there may be rain then), and go up into the forest on the next morning. Take a bus, or –

The [Brocken Railway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocken_Railway) (a steam heritage railway with regular schedule) runs right up to the summit at 1140m; that is where having snow is the most likely. The trip to the summit costs a fortune, but you may get off one station earlier for walking (with snow not uncommon at/above elevation 690), and pay a moderate fare. (Anyway the train happens to terminate early in severe winter conditions, but that will be good enough then.)

---

There are alternative destinations in Germany:

- Winterberg (Sauerland) is even a shorter trip, but *is* a ski resort,
- going to the Black Forest will take a bit longer (but that depends on where you are in the Netherlands).

Comment: There was a comment here (deleted) mentioning that there was not much snow in the Harz recently. This is true, and it is not the first time that winter is virtually absent in northern Germany, but not a rule either. This one is for the spontaneous quick trip - whenever weather allows - from NL; better book in advance and go to the Alps (more answers here) when you want to be certain about snow.

Comment: The Harz has actually sparked this question! I've been there in the snow and it was absolutely wonderful. The views along from the top of the hills/mountains, the forests, the canals for the waterworks, the nice little towns. It is very beautiful in the summer too end even in winter without snow it is nice. The last three times we were there in winter there was no snow, so I decided to put some work in finding a similar destination but with a higher probability of snow.

Answer (score 6):

You could look at a weather map, and try to identify regions that have precipitation *and* temperatures below 0°C.

There exists a snow map too: https://www.snow-forecast.com/maps/dynamic/europe?hr=6

Comment: A [snow cover map](https://zoz.cbk.waw.pl/snieg/en/) might be even more useful. Conditions can change rapidly though. But you could use it to identify a useful destination, check the weather forecast for the coming week to make sure it won't get too warm and then travel within that time period.  Won't work if you need to plan your trip a or two month in advance though.

Comment: @jkej Nice, I had been looking for a map like that but couldn't find anything

Comment: meteoblue also has various snow maps: https://www.meteoblue.com/en/weather/maps/#coords=7.64/42.494/1.08&map=snowDepth~hourly~auto~sfc~none

Comment: Weather information is indispensable in planning a winter trip. The hard part is but intersecting this information with the transport (trains) and tourism (accommodation) data layers.

Comment: For snow cover I can recommend [meteociel](https://www.meteociel.fr/modeles/icon-eu.php?ech=3&mode=46&map=560).

Comment: Unfortunately we have to plan holidays well in advance because of work. But maybe historic data can help here.

Answer (score 5):

There are places in France that have snow, hills or smaller mountains, and are not ski resorts, or minor ones. I spent winters in my childhood in places like Limousin and Auvergne.

I remember a slightly crappy ski resort called Le Lioran, with its own train station. The place was actually quite nice, although by now my memories are fuzzy. And the place is humid and cold, so we had snow every year.

I'm pretty sure there are similar places around France.

Comment: Le Lioran is not guaranteed to have snow anymore, it's fairly low in altitude

Answer (score 5):

The easiest guarantee of lots of snow is in the Alps. For an overview of skiing areas, have a look at the interactive map provided by [BERGFEX](https://www.bergfex.com/) (map icon top-right). You'll find plenty of gaps. You could double-check for snow on some live webcams, for example at [Windy.com](https://www.windy.com/-Webcams/).

Just randomly zooming in on BERGFEX brings me to Erstfeld, where there seems to be no skiing infrastructure whatsoever. Then a quick look at [Bahn.de](https://www.bahn.de/) gives you an itinerary by train with just two transfers, or just one if you're willing to take a sleeper train to Basel. You can also book through [nsinternational.com](https://www.nsinternational.com/).

And if you really want to travel on a budget and away from the crowds, just get off at any train station in the high alps, and within two hours walk you can be beyond the reach of all but the most adventurous skier. Just bring some food, a warm sleeping bag and a shovel to dig a snow hole or indeed build an igloo.

Comment: Erstfeld is at 475m, there will be rather little snow (unless climbing up the mountains)

Comment: Looking for gaps in the infrastructure will bring you to places with no infrastructure, which may be anything: residential, industrial, agricultural, military, or just desert void (certainly each one being a unique experience). Erstfeld is known for its railway installations (historic locomotive depot), and for the portal of Gotthard base tunnel.

Comment: @JanBlumschein Not sure what the point of your second comment is. As for the first comment; if you follow the approach described here you'll find many places. Erstfeld is just an example. But a quick check on Windy.com gives a webcam just 2km from Erstfeld, showing a thick blanket of snow yesterday:
https://www.windy.com/-Webcams/Switzerland/Uri/Attinghausen/Br%C3%BCsti/webcams/1292514767?46.816,8.583,12

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Ah! That webcam belongs to the top station of a lift, 1000m above the station of Erstfeld (plus 2km horizontally). This _is_ ski infrastructure, family-friendly though - hit for the OP!

Comment: I'm assuming OP is able to walk.

Comment: What if OP comes with children?

Comment: Bergfex is really good, thanks! It shows the altitude very clearly, which is a predictor for snow. And selecting 'winter tours' shows what areas are nice for walking around.

Answer (score 4):

Although there are limited winter sports areas in Scotland they are limited. You can get Eurostar from Amsterdam/Rotterdam and then either travel by rail the same day from King's Cross or get the Caledonian sleeper from Euston (a short walk from King's Cross/St Pancras where Eurostar arrives) and be in the north the next day.

Comment: There's also an overnight ferry from Amsterdam/IJmuiden to Newcastle - you might have snow in the hills around Newcastle. or take a train into Scotland.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest web searching for non-skiing activies such as:

france snow tubing

children snow play area  france

One kids park I found is https://www.valfrejus.com/en/equipement/kid-park-valfrejus/

I wouldn't rule out ski areas. Because they are used by lots of people there are many trains and buses serving them. Because they have so many hotel rooms, many have a range of prices and good availability. But smaller "family" mid-price areas will probably be best for you.

Good luck--this is a worthwhile idea that should be fun for your family.

Comment: True, it is not possible to search for 'not necessarily skiing' but it is possible to look for: trails, snowshoe trails, tubing, tobbogan etc.

Answer (score 3):

The other, more obvious answer points to Switzerland, into the mountain regions served by metre-gauge trains operated by Rhätische Bahn and Matterhorn-Gotthard-Bahn: Engadin, Bernina pass, Albula and Rhine valleys, Upper Valais …
Exemplary train service running *through* scenic winter landscape, with plenty of snow guaranteed. Hop off anywhere for a snowballfight, and continue your trip after 59 more minutes.

Next to busy and glamorous holiday resorts, there are some comparably quiet places (mandatory church, optional supermarket) still served by frequent & reliable trains (not sure if permanently booked out). And there is even a prepared [sleigh ride from one train station to another](https://www.berguen-filisur.graubuenden.ch/en/aktivitaten/winter/sledging).

Unfortunately these destinations involve a longer journey (like ~12 hours from Amsterdam CS), and they are not cheap.

Answer (score 2):

Tyrol? There's a sleeper train from Amsterdam/Utrecht/Arnhem to Innsbruck, which is one of the best know Alpine regions.

Comment: So surely OP will want to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

> France

In the winter season's weekends, TGVs direct from Paris Gare de Lyon serve [Saint-Gervais-les-Bains Le Fayet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint-Gervais-les-Bains-Le_Fayet_station), are also served directly, [Les Arcs](https://en.lesarcs.com/) through Bourg-Saint-Maurice (and a 10min funicular ride afterwards), [La Norma](https://www.la-norma.ski/) through Modane (+ 15min shuttle ride).

St Gervais being a 4h50 direct ride, Bourg-Saint-Maurice 5 hours, and La Norma being served from Saint-Michel Valloire due to the Maurienne landslide destroying the tracks between France and Italy

You can also push to the Mont Blanc, through Saint-Gervais and the emblematic [Mont Blanc Express](https://www.mont-blanc-express.ch/en/index.htm) or take the Aiguille du Midi cable car from Chamonix (again through the Mont Blanc Express).

Comment: Most of those actually ski resorts, which OP apparently wants to avoid.

Comment: And OP hasn't even said they want to ski: but to avoid skiers.